# how to call other api from my website?

Tags: java, php

i'm quite new to java ....
for a college project i m developing a website with java (Java EE) and in that website i need some information from one another website that is made with php and its API is available for use....
let me make myself a bit more clear

my website A(WITH JAVA) wants some information from website B(WITH PHP ,API available)....
so how can i get those information  ........

i guess ajax request can be made only from client side and i want to do this on server side, how can i do this please help me.....

Comment: There are something called Web-services.

Comment: which web service is for php can u tell me...

Comment: You can use e.g. SOAP (if available) or REST. depeding on what is available on your server and what the API is accepting

Comment: You need to be more specific about the API that's available to you. The answer depends on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you want to run a get with java you could use this:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;        


HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpGet requestGet = new HttpGet(url + params);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(requestGet);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: this one saved my day

Comment: @user3408036 It was a pleasure to help you :D!! if you are happy you can accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpGet requestGet = new HttpGet(url + params);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(requestGet);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
```

Use these lines to call api.
Here url is link of api and params are required parameters.